# Citation acknowledging contradiction

Tags: citations

How do you acknowledge contradictory citations? Which (if any) of the following examples would be acceptable? (My field typically has citations at the end of the sentence, so I'm finding it even more difficult to achieve this.)

example 1, making a statement that is not entirely true:
"There has been relatively little research in diet overlap of extinct animals (but/although see Smith 2007)"

example 2, acknowledging that a study has inconsistent conclusions to other studies:
"Many studies showed coexisting animals had little diet overlap (e.g. Merry 2018, but see Jones 2002)"

example 3, studies are more or less equal in opposing results:
"Studies on modern animal diet overlap have inconsistent results (Jones 2002, Merry 2018, Smith 2007)"

I've found fairly clear guidelines on how to use "citation signals" in legal writing, but this is for my thesis.

Comment: If no one is strictly forcing you to only use citations at the end of sentences I wouldn't constrain yourself to that convention at the cost of clarity.

Comment: Following on from @BryanKrause, if they *are* forcing you to cite in such a restricted way, you could split the sentence into two, point and counterpoint: "Many studies showed coexisting animals had little diet overlap (e.g. Merry 2018). In specific circumstances [define] overlap was  shown (Jones 2002)"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend being clear and actually telling the reader what your citations say, not only that they exist. I always find it very unhelpful when a claim is made in the text and supported with three citations, but I have to look them up myself to see what they actually said. (Unless I want only *assumptions* about what they say.)

Example 1:

> There has been relatively little research in diet overlap of extinct animals. One of the rare studies is Smith (2007), who found that *Tyrannosaurus Rex* and *Homo neandertalensis* had a large overlap in breakfast cereal consumption.

Example 2:

> Many studies showed coexisting animals had little diet overlap (e.g. Merry 2018 comparing *Pteranodon* and *Allosaurus*). However, Jones (2002) found a large overlap in the consumption of humans between *Tyrannosaurus Rex* and *Velociraptor mongoliensis*.

Example 3:

> Studies on modern animal diet overlap have inconsistent results: Jones (2002) found little overlap in frosted flakes consumption betweeen cats and cows, whereas Merry (2018) and Smith (2007) found large overlap in rice crispies consumption between cats and dogs, and between parakeets and humans, respectively.

Of course, this is heavily colored by the fields I am active in. If this kind of writing is uncommon in your field, this may be jarring to your advisor. I would suggest you keep this approach in mind when you read the next two or three papers and see whether this is sometimes used, or not at all.

Comment: I strongly agree. If this kind of writing is uncommon in your field, I recommend you do it anyway, as long as you have space, because it is helpful to the reader (even though these three examples would be better without the jokey aspects)

Comment: Example 2 could still work forcing the citation to the end if required.  It wouldn't be as nice, but could be done (e.g "However a large overlap was found...(Jones, 2002)")

Comment: @StephanKolassa
Thank you, this is very helpful! The examples were clear enough to push away my self-inflected confusion. I also appreciate your amusing examples!

For comparison, do you have an example of how/when (but see Jones 2002) would be used?

Comment: You could still use a "(but see Jones 2022)" if you just made a point, bolstered it with a citation, and wanted to call out that Jones (2022) differs... somehow. I would still say that it would be more useful to the reader to make explicit just *how* Jones (2022) differs from what you wrote before.